# Replace matching pairs of characters with parenthesis

Tags: replace, parentheses

It is better to describe an example. I have a latex source file (this is an ordinary text file) that has a lot of charactes `$` enclosing inline equations, something like this:

```
bla bla bla $E = mc^2$ bla blah
```

I would like to replace each ocurrence of a *matching pair* of `$` characters in the file by `\( ... \)`, like this:

```
bla bla bla \(E = mc^2\) bla blah
```

Any idea of to do this, as simple as possible? I am not sure grep is able to handle this.

Assume that the file has an *even* number of occurrences of `$`. In that case, all we have to do is replace the `$` at odd positions by `\(`, and the `$` at even positions by `\)`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
spacewrench$ cat foo
bla bla bla $E = mc^2$ bla blah
spacewrench$ sed -e 's/\$\(.*\)\$/\\(\1\\)/g' < foo
bla bla bla \(E = mc^2\) bla blah
```

`sed` can do it.  You may need to play with the number of backslashes, plus line endings if you have expressions that extend over multiple lines.

The `.*` expression is greedy, so it might only put one pair of parentheses around multiple `$` on a line...you can fix that by replacing `.*` with `[^\$]*`.

Comment: This won't replace _matching_ pairs, since there's no way to tell whether any given `$` is supposed to close a previous `$` or open a new (nested) pair.  For example, consider `$ a + $ b * c $ $`.  Should that be `( a + ) b * c ( )` or `( a + ( b * c ) )`?  (Yes, I know one makes more sense than the other, but `sed` is not that smart.)

Comment: I don't think latex is that smart either. `$` is a toggle, afaik; nesting is not possible. (`\$`, on the other hand...)